# javascript firefox iframe <html> trouble

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I have iframe on my page. In firefox, when I tab into the iframe the control goes to html tag in the iframe. (I could see this with document.activeElement.contentWindow.document.activeElement on console.) The next tab gets me to the first control in the iframe.

In IE and chrome it works fine.

Can you please help me, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `Can you please help me, what I am doing wrong?` - What do you expect? When is the code "working fine"?

Comment: In firefox, with first tab it should directly go to first control in the iframe and not to html tag. (just like IE). Actually, i have 3 iframes one below another. So if I tab from one iframe to another, for user, one extra tab is needed.

Comment: It is browser behavior, you are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong.  Firefox is focusing the root element so that a user who's just using the keyboard can scroll the iframe if he wants to.  If the focus went directly to the first text input, for example, the user wouldn't be able to scroll the frame.

And indeed, that's what happens in Chrome.  If the subframe happens to not have any text controls in it, the user can scroll it fine after tabbing to it.  If it has text controls, the user is screwed if he wants to scroll.

For what it's worth, I just reported this as https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79558 because it seems like a clear accessibility bug...